# ng-repeat doesn't seem to be working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, europeana-api

I am trying to pull all items from my array called 'collections'. When I input the call in my html I see only the complete code for the first item in the array on my page. I am trying to only pull in the 'edm.preview' which is the image of the item. I am using Angular Firebase and an api called [Europeana](http://labs.europeana.eu/api). My app allows the user to search and pick which images they like and save them to that specific user.

here is the js:

```
  $scope.users = fbutil.syncArray('users');

  $scope.users.currentUser.collections = fbutil.syncArray('collections');
  $scope.addSomething = function (something) {
    var ref = fbutil.ref('users');
    ref.child($rootScope.currentUser.uid).child('collections').push(something);
  }
  $scope.addSomething = function(item) {
      if( newColItem ) {
        // push a message to the end of the array
        $scope.collections.$add(newColItem)
          // display any errors
          .catch(alert);
       }
    };
```

and the html:

```
<ul id="collections" ng-repeat="item in collections">
  <li ng-repeat="item in collections">{{item.edmPreview}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why double ng-repeat?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I'm not an AngularJS expert but I support the Europeana developer community and saw you are using our API. I'm interested to hear what you are building. Give me a shout at james.morley@europeana.eu if you have any questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, remove the outer `ng-repeat`. You want to only add the `ng-repeat` directive to the element which is being repeated, in this case `<li>`.

Second, from your AngularJS code, it looks like you want to loop over `users.currentUser.collections` and not just `collections`:

```
 <ul id="collections">
   <li ng-repeat="item in users.currentUser.collections">{{item.edmPreview}}</li>
</ul>
```

And third, you're defining the function `$scope.addSomething` twice in your JavaScript code. Right now, the second function definition (which, incidentally, should be changed to update `$scope.users.currentUser.collections` as well) will completely replace the first.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have it working, but now I am getting an error saying $scope is not defined. I'll keep messing around with, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you pass $scope into the controller?